# view don't change while cpu on 100%

Tags: objective-c

A for loop let my CPU run on 100 %. The problem is I want to change some things on the view. For example I want to use a progressView, but everything on the view only changes when the loop is finished.

Is it possible to solve my problem?

And as always, sry for my bad english.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C - loop to change label text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325202/objective-c-loop-to-change-label-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some form of concurrency to achieve this, so that your iteration and UI updating tasks can occur in parallel with each other. Apple's [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/concurrencyprogrammingguide/Introduction/Introduction.html) provides an introduction to the various forms of concurrency available.

Answer (score 0):

Move your for loop onto an asynchronous GCD queue, being sure to put any UIKit messages on the main queue. This will free up the UI thread for any view changes that you want to occur.