# Update UILabel Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a problem updating my label and can't seem to find any solutions on the Internet. I need the label to update as soon as its text changes. I'm just using a simple observer.

```
var updateLabel: String = "" {
    didSet { 
        label.text = updateLabel  //This doesn't update
        print(updateLabel)        //This Prints
    }
}

var count: Int? = 0

while (count! < 1000000) {
    count!++
    updateLabel = "\(count!)"
}
```

I've tried this, but it didn't help.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
}

setNeedsDisplay()
```

Comment: It sounds like you might want to animate a number as it changes. You might want to review the implementation of (or just use) the open-source [UICountingLabel](https://github.com/dataxpress/UICountingLabel).

Comment: Good idea. I've used that and variants with great results.

Comment: The count was just a quick example that gives me the same problem as my original code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, controls won't update immediately, but get updated in the next run loop.

Since you are looping a million times, you're blocking updates, and 999,999 of those changes that you are trying to make to the UI won't even be applied.

The last change you make to the UI will not be committed until the run loop gets control.

As an aside, calling `setNeedsDisplay` only lets the system know that the label needs to be updated in the next run loop.  It doesn't update it immediately, as you might think.  But it's really superfluous since changing the label's text already marked the label as needing to be updated.

Comment: Are there work around? Is IT possible to update it in the current run loop?

Comment: @HovyTech well there's obviously a limit to the refresh rate of the screen... but you'd probably want to setup a `CADisplayLink`, calculate the duration between updates and increase your variable accordingly. That way the label get's updated in-line with the run loop.

Comment: I think you can create your own run loop and manage it yourself, probs best solution

Comment: @originaluser2 [UICountingLabel](https://github.com/dataxpress/UICountingLabel) uses `CADisplayLink` in exactly this way.

Comment: @HovyTech A better question might be how to run a time-consuming operation in the background, instead of on the main thread.  But if you're set on doing it that way, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6363828/4151918).