# Count up or down animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Updating UILabel in the middle of a for() loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363828/updating-uilabel-in-the-middle-of-a-for-loop)

I have a UItextfield (called result) in my app that returns a result based on a number of inputs.

I want the result to display with an animation that causes the numbers to increase from what they currently are. I don't know much about animation but I was thinking of using a for loop to achieve this.

I wrote some test code to see if this approach would work but it doesn't seem to do anything. ANy ideas where I'm going wrong or if this is even a good way of achieving this?

```
-(IBAction)test;
{
    float result = ([maintenance.text floatValue]);
    result=0;
    int i;

    for (i=1; i==100; i++) {

        //Assign result figure to result text box
        resultVal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.f",result];

        result =result+10;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating UILabel in the middle of a for() loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6363828/), [Label display not instant](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6379751/), [Loop to change label text](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6325202/), [Dynamically updating a UILabel](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6336991/)

Answer (score 1):

This code will never execute

```
for (i=1; i==100; i++) {...}
```

Also, the results of these two code snippets are completely equivalent:

```
float result = ([maintenance.text floatValue]);
result=0;

// or
float result = 0;
```

Maybe going through a C primer would be in order?