# How to Wait in Objective-C and Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, wait, performselector

I want to change my `UILabel`'s text after 2 seconds.

I tried setting my `UILabel`'s text to *"A text"*, and use `sleep(2)` and finally changing the text to *"Another text"*.

But `sleep(2)` only freezes the app and *"Another text"* is set without displaying *"A text"* for 2 seconds.

How may I display *"A text"* for 2 seconds and then show *"Another text"*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling sleep(5); and updating text field not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834062/calling-sleep5-and-updating-text-field-not-working)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use

```
[self performSelector:@selector(changeText:) withObject:text afterDelay:2.0];
```

or if you want to display it periodically, check the [`NSTimer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) class.

Answer (score 90):

I know I am late to this party. But I found people haven't mention thread sleep. If you are using GCD to call that function. You can use :

```
NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0f];
```

to delay the thread for 2 seconds.

```
[self changeText: @"A text"];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  //Here your non-main thread.
  [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0f];   
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //Here you returns to main thread.
    [self changeText: @"Another text"];
  });
});
```

**Edit 2 (Feb 2015)**

I think the NSTimer is a great solution. My solution just giving another option to achieve the goal of NSTimer.

Please read: [How do I use NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449104/2073991)

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
         target:self
         selector:@selector(doSomethingWhenTimeIsUp:)
         userInfo:nil
         repeats:NO];
```

In the class, you need this method:

```
- (void) doSomethingWhenTimeIsUp:(NSTimer*)t {
  // YES! Do something here!!
}
```

**Edit 3 (May 2016)**

In Swift 2.0, you can use this way:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, 
                                       target: self, 
                                       selector: "doSomethingWhenTimeIsUp:", 
                                       userInfo: nil, 
                                       repeats: false)
```

It creates an NSTimer's entity and adds the timer automatically to the NSRunLoop associated with the NSThread in which the timer is created.

**Edit 4 (Jun 2016)**
In Swift 2.2, the way to invoke select is:

```
#selector(doSomethingWhenTimeIsUp(_:))
```

So, it is something like:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0,
                                       target: self,
                                       selector: #selector(doSomethingWhenTimeIsUp()),
                                       userInfo: nil,
                                       repeats: false)
```

**Edit 5 (Oct 2016)**

In Swift 3, the way to invoke select is:

```
#selector(doSomethingWhenTimeIsUp)
```

So, it is something like:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0,
                     target: self,
                     selector: #selector(doSomethingWhenTimeIsUp),
                     userInfo: nil,
                     repeats: false)
```

Then, the func should looks like this:

```
@objc private func doSomethingWhenTimeIsUp(){
  // Do something when time is up
}
```

**Edit 6 (May 2018)**
In **Swift 4**, we can do as below way.

```
let delaySeconds = 2.0
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delaySeconds) {
  doSomethingWhenTimeIsUp()
}
```

Then, the func should looks like this:

```
private func doSomethingWhenTimeIsUp(){
  // Do something when time is up
}
```

Comment: This was useful for me to use in a do-while loop within a dispatch_async.  Thanks. +1

Comment: Especially for those working closely with threading, this is a much better answer. ++

Answer (score 30):

Grand Central Dispatch has a helper function `dispatch_after()` for performing operations after a delay that can be quite helpful. You can specify the amount of time to wait before execution, and the `dispatch_queue_t` instance to run on. You can use `dispatch_get_main_queue()` to execute on the main (UI) thread.

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    // do something
});
```

In **Swift 3**, the above example can be written as:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `NSTimer`, like so -

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(updateLabel:) 
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:YES];
```

Define another method `updateLabel` and do the updation there. Define your timeInterval to suite your needs...

Also setting `repeats` to `YES` makes sure that this selector is executed every 0.5 seconds (in the above case).

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this with a timer, e.g.

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self selector:@selector(eventToFire:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; // Fire every 4 seconds.
   
...

- (void)eventToFire:(NSTimer*)timer {
  // Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the view isn't updated until the end of the runloop. Instead of using sleeps try using NSTimer to set a specific time to update the view.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a timer. Using sleep will halt your entire program. Check [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

Answer (score 0):

The follow method is good.

You can replace your

> sleep(1);

with

> dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
>   dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC));