# How to make thread sleep for seconds in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

In iOS env, is it possible to make current thread sleep for seconds, then execute my code? NSTimer, GDC or any technique is okay for me.

Comment: What have you tried? Please share the code you have tried already. Also have you tried something as simple as `sleep(2);` or `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2000]`?

Comment: What do you need to achieve?

Comment: @flexaddicted I don't see it as a direct duplicate of *that*. Judging from the tags used by **Opart Code**, he does not seem to be referring to Java in any way. He may not even know any Java at all and wouldn't consider searching for this information in this way. But of course duplicate it is, there is a bunch of questions like this on SO...

Comment: @Michal I agree with you. Anyway a simple search will give a lot of results on the subject.

Comment: Thanks for all reply. I learn lot more from **Popeye** posted thread

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It would be better if you shared what you have done but it here you go.

There are a few options you can go with:

**Option 1**

```
// Standard Unix calls
sleep(); 
usleep();
```

Some documentation regarding the `sleep` function can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_%28system_call%29). You'll find that they are actually `C` functions but since `Objective-C` is a strict superset of C we can still use the `sleep` and `usleep` functions.

**Option 2**

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.000];//2 seconds
```

The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/sleepForTimeInterval:) for this method states:

> Sleeps the thread for a given time interval.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> No run loop processing occurs while the thread is blocked.

**Option 3**

```
 dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 
                              1 * NSEC_PER_SEC),
                dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                ^{ 
                     // Do whatever you want here. 
                 });
```

The `Grand Central Dispatch` route is a pretty good way of doing things as well. Here is the Apple Documentation for [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html) which is quite a good read.

There is also this question that might be pretty useful [How to Wait in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983400/how-to-wait-in-objective-c)

Comment: I think dispatch_after method is what I want. Thanks.

Comment: Option 2 halts the system

Comment: is there any requirement on SO to 'post your code'?

Comment: @NSTJ I'm confused at what you are asking. Are you talking about the OP sharing code in their post? If so it is recommended https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve the question and help find a solution that suits them best and many other reasons why it would be better to share code including shows that they have attempted to resolve their question themselves.

Comment: Indeed - it seems like the OP may not have actually done anything yet (which is fine) and I can't see the issue with asking a well structured question like he did without posting any code.  Also from the link you gave: > Not all questions benefit from including code

Comment: `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2000];` this will sleep for 2000 seconds. I'm editing because most will assume that's 2000 milliseconds and be confused with behavior (as already seen via @Itai Spector in comments above)

Answer (score 8):

it cannot be easier.

```
sleep(seconds);
```

Comment: Thank you for comment, It looks like a system level API to stop current thread. Anyway, it works for my situation.

Comment: Why not? If the answer is really simple, I don't know...what do you expect?

Answer (score 5):

Use the class method `+ (void)sleepForTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)ti`

The variable NSTimeInterval is of type double and represents the number of seconds to sleep

```
// Block for .5 seconds
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:.5];
```

Answer (score 3):

Either

```
[self performSelector:@selector(YourFunctionName) withObject:(can be Self or Object from other Classes) afterDelay:(Time Of Delay)];`
```

or

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), 
    dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //your method 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

it depends how you are creating (spawning) your threads. For example if you are creating your thread with `NSThread` class, you can use the two class methods :

```
sleepUntilDate:
sleepForTimeInterval:
```

But generally it's a bad idea to handle the threading management yourself, because multithreading programming is very hard. You can use GCD or operations queues for example to handle the multithreading in your application.