# My iOS app wont iterate through my strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I realize this is a very basic question and the other posts didnt seem to help since I am so new to this. I'm curious why A.) my for loop will not iterate through my strings (questions), and why B.) it is only printing the last question "whats your last name?" on my iOS simulator when I click my target action button. All my connections are correct, and obviously if its building, everything in my .h is ok.

I appreciate the help!

```
- (IBAction) question;
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        questionLabel.text = @"Whats your name?";
        questionLabel.text = @"Whats your age?";
        questionLabel.text = @"Whats your height?";
        questionLabel.text = @"Whats your weight?";
        questionLabel.text = @"Whats your last name?";

    }
}
```

Comment: "Xcode wont iterate through my strings" - that's correct, Xcode doesn't do **anything** with your strings. It's the for loop that does. You seriously need to get some basic idea about computers and and also some common sense, this ain't going to be good if you start "developing" iOS app lacking fundamental knowledge.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically Updating a UILabel](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6336991/), [Label display not instant with iPhone app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6379751), [NSTextField waits until the end of a loop to update](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5829977), [Loop to change label text not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6325202), [Calling sleep(5) and updating text field not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5834062)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These logs will give you an exact idea

```
- (IBAction) question;
 {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {

    NSLog(@"Iteration: %d",i);

    questionLabel.text = @"Whats your name?";
    NSLog(@"%@",questionLabel.text);

    questionLabel.text = @"Whats your age?";
    NSLog(@"%@",questionLabel.text);

    questionLabel.text = @"Whats your height?";
    NSLog(@"%@",questionLabel.text);

    questionLabel.text = @"Whats your weight?";
    NSLog(@"%@",questionLabel.text);

    questionLabel.text = @"Whats your last name?";
    NSLog(@"%@",questionLabel.text);

 }
}
```

If you want to display all questions on the same label(`questionLabel`) ,please write the below code

```
 - (IBAction) question;
 {
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {

    NSLog(@"Iteration: %d",i);

    questionLabel.text = @"Whats your name?";
    NSLog(@"%@",questionLabel.text);

    questionLabel.text = [questionLabel.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"Whats your age?"] ;
    NSLog(@"%@",questionLabel.text);

    questionLabel.text = [questionLabel.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"Whats your height?"] ;
    NSLog(@"%@",questionLabel.text);

    questionLabel.text  = [questionLabel.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"Whats your weight?"] ;
    NSLog(@"%@",questionLabel.text);

    questionLabel.text  = [questionLabel.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"Whats your last name?"] ;
    NSLog(@"%@",questionLabel.text);

 }
}
```

If you want to display all questions on the different labels ,create different `UILabel` and please write the below code

```
- (IBAction) question;
 {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {

    NSLog(@"Iteration: %d",i);

    questionLabel.text = @"Whats your name?";
    NSLog(@"%@",questionLabel.text);

    questionLabel1.text = @"Whats your age?";
    NSLog(@"%@",questionLabel1.text);

    questionLabel2.text = @"Whats your height?";
    NSLog(@"%@",questionLabel2.text);

    questionLabel3.text = @"Whats your weight?";
    NSLog(@"%@",questionLabel3.text);

    questionLabel4.text = @"Whats your last name?";
    NSLog(@"%@",questionLabel4.text);

 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm still trying to figure out why it won't display each question when I click my target action button. It still only displays last question, and I understand why but i'm not sure how to fix it. I've figured out how to do this with arrays and '-(id)initWithNibName' , but cant figure out how to have the button print each question, and then start over when done with the strings I have listed here.

Comment: The issue is simple, you are assigning the questionLabel.text as name first, next line  you again assigning it as Age, So the name text will replace and it will display Age, next line again u assigning it as height .. so So the Age text will replace and it will display height,,,, etc.. each of these changes will occurs within milli seconds. SO you cant see the changes. only you can see the "last name" .Because u are not changing ur label after assigned last name..

Comment: I have edited my answer with all the details :)

Answer (score 7):

It is iterating through your strings! It's doing it so fast that all you see is the last one.

Comment: I don't know why, but I can't stop laughing :D

Comment: As I know you know, this is not the complete explanation: the property is set five times, but only the last one is actually drawn to the screen.

Comment: Yes, @JoshCaswell, I know you know I know. :) But what I said is close enough to the truth to get the OP back on track. I don't think he's ready for properties, transactions, run loops, and the "redraw moment" yet!

Comment: Thank you matt & @JoshCaswell. I'm still trying to figure out why it won't display each question when I click my target action button. It still only displays last question, and I understand why but i'm not sure how to fix it. I've figured out how to do this with arrays and '-(id)initWithNibName' , but cant figure out how to have the button print each question, and then start over when done with the strings I have listed here. I've looked at some of the duplicate articles that use NSTimer etc. and some of the underlying things are the same but didn't help me get to my answer because I'm a noob.

Comment: @AaronWolverton You have to learn event-driven object-oriented programming. Here's a typical implementation. The instance (the view controller) has a state, the index number of the current question, maintained as an instance variable (an int), along with the corresponding list of questions, also maintained as instance variable (an NSArray of NSString). Each time you click the button, the button's action handler advances the index variable and displays the next question.

Comment: Thanks. I have the BNR Obj-C book and have gone through it twice but its not all sticking since I came from no programming. Moreover, everyone I know that develops iOS stuff tells me to put the books down and just start building apps.

Comment: Well then I guess I won't suggest that you read *my* book. :)

Comment: I may check it out, I've heard good things about O'Reilly.