# Cocoa bindings values not updating until end of process

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nstextfield

I have an `NSTextField` label whose value is bound to `controller.status`

When I call a function `[controller someFunction]` which updates the status with `[self setStatus:@"Something"];` the UI does not reflect the change until the process has completed.  The status has been successfully changed but I am using the text field as a status for the user so its value will change multiple times before the end of the function.

Why does the UI not update with each change of the status value?  It only displays at the end of the process with what the status is then.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically Updating a UILabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336991/dynamically-updating-a-uilabel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the UI not update with each
>   change of the status value?

Because the display is only updated as part of the run loop. [Here's a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6336991/643383) asked just moments ago.

If you have a lengthy process, you should move that to an operation or a background thread so that you don't block the main thread. Blocking the main thread causes your application to seem unresponsive.